# Simple javascript document.write isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery

[Here's the code in question](http://www.jsfiddle.net/T6Jqx/13/)

I'm trying to create a simple application - each of the three men has a `rel="x"` attribute attached them. I'm using `var regionId = $('img.selected-region').attr('rel');` to make the `rel` of the currently selected item the value of reginId.

I want to test this out by performing a simple `document.write(regionId)` command in a div under the pictures of the men. However, it's not working. Have I put the var regionId definition in the right place in the script window?

I'm completely new to javascript so the syntax is confusing to me - and help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Posting your source code so far would help us debug it. Without being able to see your code, my first guess is that the DOM isn't ready when you're calling document.write, and you should place it inside jQuery's $(document).ready event, or body's onLoad event.

Comment: See the first line of my question - it links to the JSFiddle page where the code is housed.

Comment: Oops -- My eyes must be going bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out http://www.jsfiddle.net/T6Jqx/15/

In the HTML, you have document.write in a script tag. At that time, the DOM may not be ready, but more importantly, it only executes once, not every time an image is clicked. I've modified it to print the "rel" attribute each time you click an image.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks of much for your help mate. Just a little clarification because I'm trying my best to learn here and don't want to use code without understanding it - the code            $('#debug').append($("img.selected-region").attr('rel')); - the $('#debug') goes to the div id="debug", .append does...something?, and $("img.selected-region").attr('rel') calls up the 'rel' attribute of the currently selected image region. Is that correct>

Comment: cool. yes, that's right. (append just inserts html at the end of that div. documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Comment: Ah, and by adding it to the .click function it ensures that it writes every time that an area is clicked. Awesome, really appreciate you taking the time to help me mate, I'm learning a lot.

Answer (score 1):

JSFiddle's script pane is executed after the document finishes loading.

Comment: I don't follow you. Do you mean I should put the var regionId =abcdefwhatever code in the html? I tried here: http://www.jsfiddle.net/T6Jqx/14/ and it's now writing the value, but it's coming back as undefined no matter where I click...

Comment: Please see edit - it's coming back as undefined - http://www.jsfiddle.net/T6Jqx/14/

Comment: That's because your selector doesn't match anything.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little? I'm quite new to javascript/jquery and don't really know what I should be looking for here. EDIT: Disregard, was answered below. Cheers.

Comment: `$('img.selected-region')` looks for `<img>` elements with a class of `selected-region`.  You don't have any.